# How to run CFRunLoop() for certain amount of time, then stop?

Tags: objective-c

I currently have some code that requires running `CFRunLoopRun()`.

This runs indefinitely. I would like to replace it with something that only runs for a set amount of time, say 30 seconds.

I tried `CFRunLoopRunInMode()`, but it exits immediately.

```
CFRunLoopRun(); // Works but never stops, I need to stop after 30s
CFStringRef mode = (__bridge CFStringRef)@"mode";
CFTimeInterval timeInterval = 10.0;
CFRunLoopRunInMode(mode, timeInterval, FALSE); // Doesn't work, syntax is wrong?, stops immediately
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a custom mode. It looks like you're just making it up for this one call. That would suggest that there are no input sources scheduled in that mode. All of the run-loop run functions exit immediately if there are no input sources.

`CFRunLoopRunInMode()` actually returns a value indicating why it exited. You should examine that.

The difference with `CFRunLoopRun()` is that it runs the run loop in the default mode (`kCFRunLoopDefaultMode`), not your custom mode. That mode almost certainly does have input sources scheduled (at least, assuming this is the main thread and thus the main run loop).

So, you could do this:

```
CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 10.0, FALSE);
```

All of that said, running the run loop for a fixed time period is rarely the right approach. What are you actually trying to achieve? What led you to conclude that you need to run the run loop for 10 seconds? Why not just return to the normal event loop and use a timer to do some work in 10 seconds?